# Можно ли как-то извне авторизовать пользователя Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

хочу прикрепить свой сайт на PHP к сайту Laravel, но никак не могу поставить пользователю нужную куку для общей сессии. Пробовал и просто ставить и через апи, но ничего не работает. Поэтому вопрос, можно ли всё-таки как-то это сделать?

Comment: Ну для конкретно авторизации "извне", можно использовать JWT.

Comment: Как это можно реализовать? Точнее как правильно создать токен, который подойдёт

Comment: Для Laravel можете использовать [пакет](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues)

Comment: Я попробовал расшифровать вручную, взяв код из файла Encrypter.php.
Вроде всё получается если сначала самому шифровать. а потом дешифровать, но когда попробовал взять реальную куку, получилось что-то такое : "574c6d40af6dc83d447efeea7ab40484194901a3|T3nsEtIqdT2Uw6Q8MZuKFTvIvReuDSYY5UpDo6BE"
Что нужно дальше делать с этими значениями?

Comment: А когда расшифровываю просто значения из базы данных, получается что-то такое: "s:32:"MQDHPMH7UT5WTRBGGEKWVH42GA4DUK6H";"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать в лоб, чтобы куку ставил сам laravel. Таблица с пользователями у ваших сайтов одинаковая ? В nginx настроен proxy_pass на определённый урл, по которому открывается корень laravel-сайта ?

В laravel-сайте делаете некий роут `/laravel/external_auth`. Он должен принимать get-параметры `user_id` (или что-то другое, по чему пользователя можно идентифицировать), `sign` и `redirect_back`.
`sign` - это например `md5($user_id.$secret)`. `$secret` помещаете в `.env` в laravel и куда-нибудь на старом сайте

В контроллере проверяете валидность `sign` логините пользователя штатным ларавеловским образом и делаете редирект на `redirect_back`, т.е. на урл на старом сайте.

На старом сайте после логина делаете редирект пользователя на ларавеловский `/laravel/external_auth` с нужными параметрами.

В итоге у пользователя в браузере будет нужная кука.

Comment: Стоит попробовать, единственная проблема что я в ларавеле вообще ничего не знаю

Comment: Если бы вы подсказали как можно залогинить пользователя, был бы весьма благодарен, днем пробовал, получилось максимум получить данные уже залогиненного пользователя

Comment: Залогиниться можно например так - `Auth::loginUsingId($userId);` . Посмотрите документацию - https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users . Можно посмотреть скринкаст https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch